# Counterexample of Lyapunov' Stability Theorem for equilbrium

Tags: stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

I know that thanks to Lyapunov' Stability Theorem one can study the stability of an equilibrium by finding a Lyapunov function associated to that equilibrium. But, is the converse true? 
Is it true that for every stable (or asymptotically stable) equilibrium a Lyapunov function can be found?